# hadoop MapReduce Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am facing below error while trying to run MapReduce job with more than one input file. Although I am able to run MapReduce job with only one input file.
I go through some posts and almost every one is saying there is firewall Issue or not setup properly hostnames in /etc/hosts file.
Even IF this is the case my MapReduce job will fail whether the input is single file or directory(multiple files)

Below is the output from console.

```
    INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201505201700_0005
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 16%

INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201505201700_0005_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputAMR-DEV02.local
WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputAMR-DEV02.local
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 16%
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201505201700_0005_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
    Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputEmbeddedQASrv.local
WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputEmbeddedQASrv.local
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 16%
```

Note. EmbeddedQASrv.local(ip address. 192.168.115.80) and AMR-DEV02.local(ip address. 192.168.115.79) are my slave node host names.

My Hadoop cluster is consisting of 1 Master and 2 Slaves.

This is the command I am running from console.(emp_dept_data is a directory contains empData and deptData files)

```
hadoop jar testdata/joindevice.jar JoinDevice emp_dept_data output15
```

However, If i run this command MapReduce job gets successed(single file as input)

```
hadoop jar testdata/joindevice.jar JoinDevice emp_dept_data/empData output16
```

Here is my /etc/hosts file entry set up Master node. However same entry's were copied to my slave nodes also.

```
127.0.0.1               amr-dev01.local amr-dev01 localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
#Hadoop Configurations
192.168.115.78    master
192.168.115.79    slave01
192.168.115.80     slave02
```

I am clueless for what is wrong and where to check for exact root cause.

Comment: Can anyone guide me what is wrong with my code. If required, I will share my entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was with /etc/hosts file. I commented my local host configuration. 
amr-dev01.local amr-dev01 localhost
and Instead of specifying different names like master, slave01, slave02...I used same hostnames

192.168.115.78    amr-dev01 
192.168.115.79    amr-dev02